# If i change the ulimit values on a production server, will it disrupt existing processes already running on the server?

Tags: linux, production-environment

We have a requirement to change the ulimit values on a production server as the current ones configured are not up to the mark.
However, already many java processes are running on the server and we do not want to disrupt any of them.

Can we change the ulimit values on the production server on the fly ?

This is for 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: I guess this should be moved to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Processes inherit resource limits from their parent processes. The shell builtin `ulimit` changes the shell's own resource limits and thus *those of its future children*. Changing values in `limits.conf` will change future login shell's  resource limits, and thus those *of their children*. Both wil not change the limits of already running processes.

Of course, the already running processes may feel other processes getting more resource-hungry. This may make them run out of memory sooner, for example.

To get *or set* the resource limits of already running processes, newer linuxes have the [prlimit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html)
command. As an example, to change the `nproc` limit af a running process:

```
prlimit --pid $MY_SERVER_PID --nproc=unlimited
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I completely agree with your point :). However, my question still remains unanswered. If i change the values in this file /etc/security/limits.conf , will it have an impact on the existing running java processes?

Comment: No, how could it? `man limits.conf` states: _Also, please note that all limit settings are set per login. They are not global, nor are they permanent; existing only for the duration of the session_

Comment: oh okay okay. Thanks Hans Lab. Noted :) .